# Making new lists out of other list variables

Tags: python, list, math, append

When i want to make a new list out of carefully selected integer variables, and ask for the sum of the new list, the answer i get is always 0.

```
    else:
        if "--" in epart:
            epart = epart[2:]
            esplit = [int(epart) for epart in esplit]
            total.append(epart)
        else:
            epart = [int(epart) for epart in esplit]
            total.append(epart)

print sum(total)
```

At the top of the code is:

```
total = []
```

***How do I get the code to print the sum of the totals***, if:

```
esplit = ["34", "-3", "5", "--4"]
for epart in esplit:
```

Rather then 0, the program shoud print 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use "string.replace" to turn "--" into "" and then convert values into `int`:

```
>>> esplit = ["34", "-3", "5", "--4"]
>>> sum([int(itm.replace("--", "")) for itm in esplit])
40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
esplit = ["34", "-3", "5", "--4"]
print sum([int(elem[2:]) if "--" in elem else int(elem) for elem in esplit])
```